# How to play bgm in my app using Service or MediaPlayer?

Tags: java, android

My APP has 3 activities named "MainActivity", "LevelActivity" and "GameActivity". Now I want to play BGM in MainActivity and LevelActivity. When I jump from Main to Level, I don't want the music to start from the beginning. So I use Service to play BGM.

But the problem is that if I don't override onStop() in MainActivity, the BGM is still playing after I clicked the "HOME" button. But if I override onStop() in MainActivity, the BGM will stop when I jump from Main to Level.

```java
public class MusicService extends Service {
    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
    // my codes...
    }
    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    // my codes...
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        if (mediaPlayer != null) {
            mediaPlayer.stop();
            mediaPlayer.release();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
```

What should I do to stop BGM when I press "HOME"?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do a trick by adding a `boolean` variable .

1- create a `boolean` variable `isAppStillRunning = false`

2- then when you want to start level activity make `isAppStillRunning = true` before `startActivity()`

3- whenever you go back to MainActivity make `isAppStillRunning = false`

now in `onStop()` in your `MainActivity` ,

```
if(!isAppStillRunning){
//do the proccess to stop music
}
```

Comment: I hope the BGM plays in `MainActivity` and `LevelActivity` and I can achieve this by `Service`. My problem is that if I use `Service`, the BGM keeps playing after I click HOME because my app is not killed and the service is still running. I want to stop my service when user click "HOME" button.

Comment: so yo stop your service if  isAppStillRunning =  false , you didn't get my answer ?